# LU factorization Algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

How to show that the LU Factorization Algorithm requires $n^3/3-n/3$ multiplications/divisions and $n^3/3-n^2/2+n/6$ additions/subtractions?

Comment: What is $LU$ ? can you clarify ?

Comment: Are you familiar with how similar results are derived for Gaussian Elimination? LU Decomposition is basically the same thing.

Comment: It's LU decomposition as Alex R. said.

Comment: Yes I am pretty familiar with Gaussian Elimination, but I don't see how that is related with this question. Could you please elaborate it? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I think I got it! Thanks a lot.